# How to get Intermediate LastInsertID from two insert operations?

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id

Part of my query is shown below. I am using ASP.net with C#. I want to get the 'LastRegionID' into my C# code at the end of the query. Currently, I always get the last_ID post insert_region_cost. But I want is after region insert which is 'LastRegionID'. Is this possible? Is there another way I could achieve what I want?

```
                    string Query = @"INSERT INTO region (" +
                                    "REGION_USER_ID," +
                                    "REGION_NICK_NAME," +
                                    "REGION_POLYGON) " + 
                                "VALUES (" +
                                    "@Parameter1," +
                                    "@Parameter2," +
                                    "PolygonFromText(@Parameter3)); " +

                                "SET @'LastRegionID' = LAST_INSERT_ID();" +

                                "INSERT INTO region_cost (" +
                                    "REGION_ID," +
                                    "REGION_COST," +
                                    "REGION_COST_NICK_NAME," +
                                    "REGION_NOTES) " +
                                "VALUES (" +
                                    "@'LastRegionID'," +
                                    "@Parameter4," +
                                    "@Parameter5," +
                                    "@Parameter6);";
```

Part of C# code ...

```
                    if (sqlSuccess > 0)
                {
                    oDBStatus.LastUpdatedKey =  @LastRegionID ???';
                    oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.SUCCESS;
                    oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.SUCCESSFULLY_DATA_INSERTED);
                }
                else
                {
                    oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.ERROR;
                    oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.ERROR_NO_RECORDS_UPDATED);
                }
                return oDBStatus;
```

Comment: Can you split your query into two queries? Then you can read the generated id in C# and use it in your second query.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes that's an option but wanted to check if there is another way I could do it without splitting it.